# Golang, Go, как убрать пробелы? На личном примере

Tags: golang

Помогите пожалуйста, как убрать лишние пробелы в строке в golang. Я пытаюсь записать строку в массив, при этом не могу поставить условие что, если после слова идёт более одного пробела не добавлять их, т.е. чтобы после каждого слова записался лишь один пробел, а если их более двух то пусть останется один, делал как, if i != ' ' {} но так убирается лишь первый, а как убрать остальные за ним не знаю.

---

```
   for _, i := range s {
  if i != ' ' {
   r += string(i)
  }
  if i == ' ' {
   array = append(array, r)
   r = ""
  }
 }
```

---

```
"Hello     world"  ->    "Hello", "world"
```

нужно чтобы вот так стало
а в массив записывается как `"Hello","","","","", "world"`
тут скорее всего вопрос в том как убрать лишние пробелы чтобы в массив не записались пустые строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас уже почти всё есть. После добавления слова вы его обнуляете. Достаточно не добавлять `r` когда оно пустое.

```
    for _, i := range s {
        if i != ' ' {
            r += string(i)
        }
        if i == ' ' {
            // Не добавляем пустые слова
            if r != "" {
                array = append(array, r)
                r = ""
            }
        }
    }
    // Добавляем последнее слово
    if r != "" {
        array = append(array, r)
    }
```

Тестовый пример `"  Hello   world  !"` -> `Hello`,`world`,`!`